# selecting among files already stored on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to `R` and `Shiny` and I have some data files stored on my `Shiny` server.

What I want to do is to choose a file based upon user selection and then read that file into a data frame.

I am currently getting an `object not found error`, although the name is being transferred properly to the server UI.

Here is some code, fisrt `server.r`

```
    library(shiny)
    library(datasets)
    filenames<-list.files(path="~/qc",pattern="\\.csv$")
    shinyServer(function(input,output){

    output$choose_dataset<-renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset","Data set",filenames)
    })
    output$data_table<-renderTable({
    selFile<-get(input$dataset)
    mydat<-read.csv(selFile$name,header=T)
    head(mydat,50)
    })
    })
```

Here is the `ui.r`

```
    library(shiny)
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel(
    "Files Selection"
    ),
    sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset")
    ),
    mainPanel(
             tabsetPanel(
                         tabPanel("plot",plotOutput("plot"),id="myplot"),
                         tabPanel("Data",tableOutput("data_table"),id="myTab"),
                         id="Plot_Data"
                         )
    )
    ))
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: it would help if you show some code

Comment: How can we put files on shiny server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a few small changes and it works for me. Try and see this works for you as well.

In `server.R` I moved the selectInput() to UI.R, and I moved the filenames variable to UI.R as well.
Now, since `input$dataset` in a file, you don't get the `get()` command.

#### Server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  output$data_table<-renderTable({
    #selFile<-get(input$dataset)
    mydat<-read.csv(input$dataset, header=T)
    head(mydat,50)
  })
})
```

#### The updated UI.R

```
library(shiny)

filenames<-list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(
    "Files Selection"
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                label = "Choose Dataset",
                filenames
                )    
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("plot",plotOutput("plot"),id="myplot"),
      tabPanel("Data",tableOutput("data_table"),id="myTab"),
      id="Plot_Data"
    )
  )
))
```

Try this and you shouldn't be getting the `object not found` error. You can use these files as the basis and build on top of these.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You very much. Its works but just for my knowledge what was wrong doing it my way. Thanks again.

Comment: +1, but prompts another question: in your solution, you are loading the data inside of output$data_table<-renderTable.  This would seem to make it inaccessible to other output panels.  Sure, you could load the data the same way in each panel, but what if the file is very large -- for performance, wouldn't it be better to load it just once?  I have tried loading the data immediately after calling shinyServer, and "assign"ing it to envir=.GlobalEnv but so far no luck.  Any suggestions?  Thanks again.